# Make 0.000 display as 0.000 and not 0 in Excel

Tags: excel

When I type 0.000, I want the cell to display "0.000" and not "0". How do I stop all of this ridiculous autoformating in Excel.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. This site is for questions related to programming, please take a look at https://superuser.com/

Comment: It's a simple matter of changing the formatting of those cells. In your case you might just need to format cells as number with three decimals.

Answer (score 1):

It is not ridiculous, it is likely the way MS designed it, thinking it will be comfortable for most users (sometimes I disagree with the design of MS, but perhaps not this time).

You have to set the number format to Number, and then set the number of decimal places to 3.